# NSURL object from initWithString gives -[NSURL length] error

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, nsstring

I'm trying to find a file with a path, then delete it using the NSFileManager class. the `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` does return a string, so I dont' understand why its failing on a valid parameter.

```
NSError *error;

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[info
              objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];


if ([manager isDeletableFileAtPath: [info 
                  objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]]) {
    BOOL success = [manager removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
   , reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175ede10'
```

Comment: Do an NSLog(@"%@",[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

Comment: According to the documentation, the value of the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` key is a `NSURL` and not a `NSString` (as the *name* of the key also indicates).

Comment: @LordZsolt It prints the full path of the file.

Comment: Maybe you pass nil string like @""

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says for `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`:

> Specifies the filesystem URL for the movie. The value for this key is
>   an NSURL object.

And your error message says the same:

Therefore

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

if ([manager isDeletableFileAtPath:url]) {
    BOOL success = [manager removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path:%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be help you.

Try this

```
NSString *urlStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [info
              objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] URLWithString:urlStr];
```

than you are directly assigning URL

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[info
              objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not getting the  URL string in dictionary because `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]` don't provide url for picked image.

Documentaton says:

> The Assets Library URL for the original version of the picked item.
>   After the user edits a picked item—such as by cropping an image or
>   trimming a movie—the URL continues to point to the original version of
>   the picked item.

But you can get the image as UIImage like:

```
UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[info
              objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
```

with this line

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[info
              objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
```

i am not sure that it will solve your problem. But i feel that it should solve your problem because for file manager `URLWithString:` is not working as the string contains file path so you have to use `fileURLWithPath:`

Answer (score 0):

First check that your objectforkey value what it is returning. If it is returning url then in your code third line which you have written initWithString just replace to initWithUrl and try.

Comment: Basically, using NSString instead seems to work.

`NSString *path = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] absoluteString];`

And all i've had to change is `removeItemAtURL` to  `removeItemAtPath`.

Comment: Yes correct but in your code you are using removeitematurl so i commented on this if you use string it will be great:)

Comment: Your suggestion to use initWithURL is correct. I guess my comment should have been more meta, but anyway I've learned it's more of a matter of staying consistent when writing code! That's what I was trying to say. :)