# Comparing empty NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurl

I need your help. I have an NSURL object I get from this

```
NSURL *myImageUrls = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"url"];
if(myImageUrls == nil){
    NSLog(@"URL empty %@", myImageUrls);
}
else{
    //NSURL *url = imageUrls;
    NSLog(@"Image URL:%@", myImageUrls);
}
```

The NSLog shows Image URL: meaning the myImageUrls is empty but the if statement never get printed. How do I get it to print if the NSURL object is empty. I have tried myImageUrls == null and [myImageUrls length] =0 but still the if block never get printed.

Comment: [NSURL doesn't have a `length` property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724028/nsurl-object-from-initwithstring-gives-nsurl-length-error).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your `NSLog` prints "Image URL:" that doesn't indicate that your `NSURL` is nil or null; it indicates that your `NSURL`'s *string* is empty. If your `NSURL` was null but still executing that second conditional, your `NSLog` would print: "Image URL: (null)" instead.

To check whether your `NSURL`'s string is empty (since it seems as if you're storing `NSURL`'s in all indexes of your array, but simply storing an `NSURL` with an empty string at the "empty" indices), change your conditional to the following:

```
if(myImageUrls.absoluteString.length == 0){
    NSLog(@"URL empty %@", myImageUrls);
}
else{
    //NSURL *url = imageUrls;
    NSLog(@"Image URL:%@", myImageUrls);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lyndsey for the brilliant answer. You have saved me from pulling my hair off.

Answer (score 4):

NSURL contains a method [checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:)

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSError *err;
    if ([myURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"resource not reachable");
    }
```

Comment: I thought this was what the OP was asking for at first, but I think he/she's not actually asking for the validity of the path...only how to tell whether the  NSURL is nil. Great answer though and I'm sure it may be useful to future answer-seekers.

Comment: @Chase, you have extended my options for check for valid URLs. Thanks man.

Comment: Without having it ever used I wanted to add that according to the documentation this can only be used for "file URLs". @Chase: Are you using this for "Links" as well?